# Как сверстать такой резиновый svg блок?

Tags: html, css, svg

Как сделать svg блок такой формы?: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И главное чтобы его ширина ровнялась 40% от блока родителя. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  outline: 1px solid yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg width="40%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <polyline points="50,25 150,25 150,170 65,170 50,155 50,25" stroke="red" fill="none"></polyline>
  </svg>
</div>
```